# make configuration to Jboss7.1.1.Final to send big size JSON data via Http Post

Tags: json, http-post, jboss7.x, server.xml

I'm having json which has large size and when it exceeds 5kb , it throws exception

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) at
    org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149) at
    org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110) at
```

http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/08/05/how-to-configure-maxjsonlength-in-asp.net-ajax-applications.aspx

as per above link there is a following format

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000">
    </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

we can set maxJsonLength 
So same way Is there any configuration needs to do in Jboss7.1.1.Final to  maximize size of json to accept large json?
If yes please provide syntax.
Also I've gone through some links about maxpostsize will it be helpful in this?
Main concern is when client sends large size json data  via HttpPost , it throws exception as above while Jboss7.1.1.Final is used

Answer (score 0):

In Jboss7.1.1.Final we need to add following entry in standalone.xml

```
<system-properties>
     <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.MAX_HEADER_SIZE" value="1000"/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: The question is about the HTTP Body size, not about the HTTP Header size.